# How to overlap the input with div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make custom radio button and I want to overlap the `<input type="radio"` into `div`.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+div {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(13, 50, 218);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="favorite_pet" value="Parrot">
<div>Parrot</div><br>
<input type="radio" name="favorite_pet" value="Dog">
<div>Dog</div><br>
```

The main goal is to select by text `div` instead of radio button.

**Current Layout:**

[image]

**Expected Layout:**

[image]

How can I select the div instead of radio button with overlapping?

Comment: Your stated goal isn't a goal. It's a means to a goal. What's the _actual_ goal here? To hide the appearance of the radio button?

Comment: Why are you not using a label?

Comment: if you want the expected output just  hide radio button and on click of div just change background color of div and use Jquery to set the radio button.

Comment: @isherwood, Thanks! The goal is to use div's as radio button instead of that round shape radio. That's what I referred in image 2. I don't know how to do.

Comment: Again, there's no goal to use divs. The goal is apparently to change the appearance, right? See http://xyproblem.info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a label with for and hide the radio button

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(13, 50, 218);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="favorite_pet" value="Parrot" id="rb1">
<label for="rb1">Parrot</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="favorite_pet" value="Dog" id="rb2">
<label for="rb2">Dog</label><br>
```

If you have issues giving them ids, you can wrap the whole thing in a label and use another element for the text like a span.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(13, 50, 218);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="favorite_pet" value="Parrot">
  <span>Parrot</span>
</label><br>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="favorite_pet" value="Dog">
  <span>Dog</span>
</label><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text in label elements:

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+span {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgb(13, 50, 218);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="favorite_pet" value="Parrot">
<span>Parrot</span></label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="favorite_pet" value="Dog">
<span>Dog</span></label><br>
```

Then change your divs to spans since the divs can't exist in labels.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap `input` inside `label`.

```css
label, span{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span{
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
input[type="radio"] + span:before {
  content: '\2610'; 
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span:before {
  content: '\2611';  
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group">
  <span>Parrot</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group">
  <span>Dog</span>
</label>
```

Comment: This does not achieve the required output.